# What to do with model general attributes in django models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

What should be done with django model attributes that are common to all instances of the model? For example, if I had a django model of an office, where each office has a room number and a phone number and was in a particular city, I could do something like this:

```
class Office(models.Model):
    room = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

But what if I was defining a django model of an office where all instances of the model had, by definition, the same city? I could do something like this:

```
class LondonOffice(models.Model):
    room = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    city = models.CharField(default='London', max_length=20)
```

but in that case, the `city` field is superfluous and creates an unnecessary column in database. Would it be better to do something like this

```
class LondonOffice(models.Model):
    room = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    city = 'London'
```

and so create a database table with only two columns?

In this trivial example, the extra db column would not be a real problem. However, in the real examples I am considering, I would have a larger number of these model-wide attributes and creating an extra and unnecessary column for each seems like a waste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd move `city` into a separate model and create a [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) to it from `Office`:

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Office(models.Model):
    room = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
```

Or, if the list of cities is static and pre-defined, you can use [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices):

```
CITIES = (
    (0, 'London'),
    (1, 'New York'),
    (2, 'Moscow'),
)

class Office(models.Model):
    room = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    city = models.CharField(choices=CITIES)
```